# Delphi XE8 program is 50 KByte bigger after parallel Delphi 10.2.2 installation

Tags: delphi, tms

I compiled a VCL program with TMS Diagram Studio components with Delphi XE8.
After that I installed Delphi 10.2.2 on the same VM without TMS components.

Now I compiled the program again with Delphi XE8.
There should be no differences, but the exe-file is now 50 KBytes bigger than before. (I checked XE8 bpl-files but they are old.)

Why is the exe-file bigger than before?

Is it a known Delphi feature to manipulate older parallel installed Delphi IDE's?

Best regards

Comment: 50KB is nothing in comparison to the resulting exe size. Size doesn't matter, and you should just ignore it. The fact that the size changed may come from a lot of factors, even if XE8 will not use the 10.2.2 bpl. For instance, some shared Embarcadero libraries may have been updated during 10.2.2 setup.

Comment: @J... The code might have changed. We are looking at compiled code not source code here. New compiler, potentially new output.

Comment: @all The differences with the new Delphi 10.2.2 are accepted, but I compiled two times with the same Delphi XE8 Compiler. I'm astonished that I get 2 different results.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, I misread the question - the situation seems to be that the exe size changed for the same build in the same IDE with the same compiler (XE8) before and after installing (but not actually using) D10.2.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez  Are there any such libraries shared across compiler versions?  I generally thought this was not possible - that the compiler can only link modules that it has built itself.  10.2 does install new shared libraries, but they would not be linkable with the old XE8 compiler, I would have thought.

Comment: I wrote that the bpl won't be used accross versions, but perhaps the build itself may depend on some other tools, e.g. for resource linking, or the msbuild version. I guess that you have to modify the `path` env variable to get rid of any reference to 10.2 `bin` folder, or just call the plain `dcc`command line compiler (not the msbuild system), then try again...

Comment: What actually changed? Is the path different. Are you running the same executables to perform the build? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: The compiled EXE also includes resources for icons and manifest(s) that may have been updated / changed with the install of 10.2.2.